# Using prism.js inside lit webcomponent

Tags: javascript, typescript, lit, prismjs

I use lit webcomponents with the vite + typescript template. Now i am trying to create my own code block web-component. For syntax highlighting I wanted to use [prism js](https://prismjs.com/download.html), so i went to their page, selected my favorite languages, downloaded both css and js file and tried adding them to my webcomponent.

I just copy-pasted the css file into an ``` css`` ```, which should work just fine. But i am rather lost on how to add the js file.

Here is what i did to use the .js file:

1. Set `"allowJs": true` in the tsconfig.json.
2. `import * as prism from '../prism.js';` in myFile.ts, where i have my component.

But even if i just try to run `prism.highlightAll()` I get.

```
Uncaught TypeError: prism.highlightAll is not a function
    at myFile.ts:116:19
```

I am still rather new to the js/ts ecosystem so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone finds this, i somewhat managed to do it:

1. `npm install prismjs -s` (v1.28.0)
2. `npm install @types/prismjs -d` (v1.26.0)
3. In my .ts file with the webcomponent do:

```js
import * as Prism from 'prismjs';
import 'prismjs/components/prism-typescript'; // Language
import 'prismjs/components/prism-fsharp'; // Language
```

5. Use it as expected: `Prism.highlight(code, Prism.languages[language], language)`
6. I copy&pasted the css into an lit webcomponent ``` css`` ``` block.

I got the idea from [here](https://gist.github.com/awran5/b2fb99b91d279b700aff6d3a0f1f223d)

Comment: Add `import 'prismjs/components/prism-markup-templating.js'` on a second line if you are getting `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tokenizePlaceholders')`